# Getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException"Exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I wanted to invoke testng programmatically. Not eclipse plug-in.

I have associated "testng-6.8.21.jar" and running through eclipse and i ran below code:

```
import org.testng.TestNG;

public class SampCls 
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            TestNG test=new TestNG();
        }
}
```

Getting below exception. How can i overcome this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
    at SampCls.main(SampCls.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Change:**

```
Class cls = Class.forName("TestSuite.TestCases.AddContactHappyPath").getClass();
test.setTestClasses(new Class[] { cls });
```

**By:**

```
 test.setTestClasses(new Class[] { AddContactHappyPath.class });
```

**All code is**

```
import org.testng.TestNG;
import com.xxx.test.others.AddContactHappyPath;

public class SampCls {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        TestNG test = new TestNG();
         test.setTestClasses(new Class[] { AddContactHappyPath.class });
         test.run();
    }
}
```

**TestNG code is:**

```
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class AddContactHappyPath {

    @Test()
    public void AddContactHappyPathTest() {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

**Console result:**

```
[TestNG] Running:
  Command line suite

hello world

===============================================
Command line suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: As the class exists in a package, i suppose we need to provide the complete path like Class.forName("TestSuite.TestCases.AddContactHappyPath") and the below worked for me: test.setTestClasses(new Class[] { Class.forName("TestSuite.TestCases.AddContactHappyPath") });

Comment: I update the code with the testNG in a other package. I add import com.xxx.test.others.AddContactHappyPath;

Answer (score 17):

If you use a **Maven project**, you need add this dependancy:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
    <version>1.48</version>
</dependency>
```

the class **com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException** is inside

If you use **a project without Maven** you need add this jar file at your classpath:

```
jcommander-1.48.jar
```

You can download this jar file on [central.maven.org -> jcommander-1.48.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/beust/jcommander/1.48/jcommander-1.48.jar)

Comment: As i mentioned, i am not using any maven anything. I just downloaded this jar, launched eclipse, referenced this jar in build path, and wrote the above 3 lines of code. When i run @Test public void hello(){Syso("hello")} it is working fine. But when i invoke testng programatically, it is throwing that exception.

Comment: import org.testng.TestNG;

public class SampCls {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestNG test = new TestNG();
    }
} is OK, can you give all code please?

Comment: Some how now my test is not invoked, Can you help me? import org.testng.TestNG;

public class SampCls 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
  {
   TestNG test=new TestNG();
   Class cls=Class.forName("TestSuite.TestCases.AddContactHappyPath").getClass();
   test.setTestClasses(new Class[] {cls});
   test.run();
  }
}    Following is my test. what i am missing: package TestSuite.TestCases;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class AddContactHappyPath 
{
 @Test()
 public void AddContactHappyPathTest()
 {
  System.out.println("hello world");
 }
}

Comment: Output in console is: [TestNG] Running:
  Command line suite


===============================================
Command line suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

Comment: @sgrillon- thanks, adding jcommander-1.48.jar worked for me :)

Comment: how to check a project is having maven or not ?

Answer (score 0):

As @sgrillon correctly pointed out, you need the correct Maven dependency, but also the shade plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin) to package a Uber-jar including all Maven dependencies for easy execution.
This is what should be included in your `pom.xml`:

```
...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
      <version>1.48</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
              <shadedClassifierName>runnable</shadedClassifierName>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
```

After you build the Maven package, you'll get your regular `my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` file and also a `my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runnable.jar`.
This is what you should run, with the command:

```
$ java -jar my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runnable.jar
```

You can verify with this command:

```
$ jar tvf my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runnable.jar
```

that the shaded jar contains the JCommander classes (and those of all the other Maven dependencies), while the regular one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was to install TestNg. I referred this link [here](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/testng-framework-selenium-tutorial-12/). As I was using latest version of eclipse, Eclipse MarketPlace option didn't work for me, if it works for you then great. Else goto Help -> Install new software and work with http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/  After installation refer 1st link I mentioned to continue. All the best !!