# How to solve ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I'm new to developing in JAVA and I have the problem below when compiling a class in Eclipse.
The error while compiling is this below:

*"Java Virtual Machine Launcher
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again"*

Followed by error:

*"Java Virtual Machine Launcher
A Java Exception has occurred."*

In the console, the error presented is what is below:

```
*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 7 more*
```

Can someone help me?
Thankful.

AppTest.java

```
package all_Exercices.Different_Browsers;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;


public class AppTest
{
    WebDriver driver;

    @Parameters("browser")
    public void verifypageTitle(String browserName) 
    {
        if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SeleniumGecko\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("IE"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\SeleniumGecko\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://shopcart-challenge.4all.com/");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

crossbrowser.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">
  <test name="FirefoxTestCases">
  <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
  <classes>
    <class name="all_Exercices.Different_Browsers.AppTest"/>
  </classes>    
  </test> <!--Test -->
    <test name="ChromeTestCases">
  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
  <classes>
    <class name="all_Exercices.Different_Browsers.AppTest"/>
  </classes>    
  </test> <!--Test -->
    <test name="IETestCases">
  <parameter name="browser" value="ie"/>
  <classes>
    <class name="all_Exercices.Different_Browsers.AppTest"/>
  </classes>    
  </test> <!--Test -->
</suite> <!--Suite -->
```

POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>4all_Exercices</groupId>
  <artifactId>Different_Browsers</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Different_Browsers</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Good you posted all the details, like stack-trace (log), your java-environment (eclipse using maven, JVM). When asking about exceptions it's best to put __exception-name in title__ and __stacktrace in body__ of the question. Please also add your maven `POM.xml` file!

Comment: Hi @hc_dev, I had to create a new Maven project in Eclipse. This one I mentioned was a simple Java project. Therefore, I could not find the POM.xml file.
I changed the above codes in the post, but the error remained the same.
I put the POM.xml file as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException"Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30435688/getting-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-beust-jcommander-parameterexception)

Answer (score 0):

#### What causes the error

If a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` or `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exception is thrown, it means that the class mentioned in the message (here: `com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException`) was not found by JVM on the class-path.

Any part of your program, most probably the test-launcher (TestNG, or in your case JUnit), seems to use the command-line parser 
**JCommander** of *Cedric Beust*.

#### How to solve

Adding the needed class (in this case the whole jar) to your build class-path should enable the JVM to find and load it. Since you have a Maven project you can simply **add the dependency to your POM.xml** inside the `dependencies` element/tag:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
  <version>1.71</version>
</dependency>
```

See [JCommander Download section](http://www.jcommander.org/#_download).

#### See also

This question describes a similar problem: [Getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException"Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30435688/getting-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-beust-jcommander-parameterexception#30435822)