# how to execute a testng xml file from the bash command line?

Tags: java, linux, xml, testng, classpath

Looking to [use](https://askubuntu.com/q/1355494/847449) this `test.xml` from `bash`:

```
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle$ echo $CLASSPATH
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/testng/testng/debian/testng-debian.jar
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle$ ls /usr/share/maven-repo/org/testng/testng/debian/testng-debian.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/testng/testng/debian/testng-debian.jar
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle$ cat test.xml


<suite name="Hello World">
<test name="simple test">
<classes>
<class name="testng_gradle.TestApp" />
</classes>
</test>
</suite>



nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle$ tree
.
├── app
│   ├── build.0
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   │   ├── java
│   │   │   │   └── testng_gradle
│   │   │   │       └── App.java
│   │   │   └── resources
│   │   └── test
│   │       ├── java
│   │       │   └── testng_gradle
│   │       │       └── AppTest.java
│   │       └── resources
│   └── test.xml
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle
└── test.xml

12 directories, 11 files
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle$ cat app/src/test/java/testng_gradle/AppTest.java 
/*
 * This Java source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package testng_gradle;

import org.testng.annotations.*;
import static org.testng.Assert.*;

public class AppTest {
    @Test public void appHasAGreeting() {
        App classUnderTest = new App();
        assertNotNull(classUnderTest.getGreeting(), "app should have a greeting");
    }
}
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle$ java org.testng.TestNG test.xml
Error: Unable to initialize main class org.testng.TestNG
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle$ uname -a
Linux mordor 5.11.0-25-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 9 23:06:29 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle$
```

The example command is:

```
java org.testng.TestNG testng1.xml
```

is the problem with the `xml` configuration file perhaps?  Can't see how that would relate to the error above.

Comment: *Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException* Unless that class is bundled into the one and only jar on your classpath, then you're going to get that exception. Either use a shaded (fat) jar or put the dependency jars on the classpath too

Comment: yes, that was a concern @g00se and thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

partial solution:

```
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle/app$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle/app$ export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/testng.jar:/usr/share/java/jcommander.jar:/home/nicholas/NetbeansProjects/testng_gradle/app/src/main/java/testng_gradle/App.java:/home/nicholas/NetbeansProjects/testng_gradle/app/src/test/java/testng_gradle/AppTest.java
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle/app$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle/app$ echo $CLASSPATH
/usr/share/java/testng.jar:/usr/share/java/jcommander.jar:/home/nicholas/NetbeansProjects/testng_gradle/app/src/main/java/testng_gradle/App.java:/home/nicholas/NetbeansProjects/testng_gradle/app/src/test/java/testng_gradle/AppTest.java
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle/app$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle/app$ cat test.xml 
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
 
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Regression1"   >
    <packages>
      <package name="test.sample" />
   </packages>
 </test>
</suite>
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle/app$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle/app$ pwd
/home/nicholas/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle/app
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle/app$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle/app$ java org.testng.TestNG test.xml
[TestNG] Running:
  /home/nicholas/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle/app/test.xml


===============================================
Suite1
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

nicholas@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/testng_gradle/app$
```

as a start.

**However, it shows that ZERO tests have been run.**

see also:

[Getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException"Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30435688/4531180)